# UITextField in cell that is not visible has userInteractionEnabled set to No

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, cocoa

I am trying to skip over text fields that are disabled when a user navigates through my tableview.  However, when they reach the bounds of the visible cells, everything gets out of whack because I am trying to detect if a text field is disabled, and if so, then recursively call my method again to navigate one more time.  ie.  if user presses a button to navigate to the right, and that text field is disabled, recursively call a right press again.

It seems, any text fields in cells outside what is visible are disabled. once the user reaches the edges of the table I go into infinite loops, or things just break.

here is my section of code where I make my enabled check and if not make my recursive call.  This really shouldn't be that complicated.  Logically all I want to do is detect if the text field we just moved to is disabled and if so, just initiate the same button press again.  Nothing fancy.

*edit* with some playtesting it has become apparent that the nextTextFieldSelection is coming back as null, although the destinationIndexPath and newTag values are correct.  Is it possible requesting an indexPath not visible is causing a null return?

```
     //logic to move to next text field and manually scroll the tableViewbased on button input is here

    nextTextFieldSelection = (UITextField *)[[_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:destinationIndexPath] viewWithTag:newTag];
    if (nextTextFieldSelection.userInteractionEnabled == NO) {
        switch (arrowButton.tag) {
            case NumericKeyboardViewLeftArrow:
                currentTextField = nextTextFieldSelection;
                [self numericKeyboardView:(VS_NumericKeyboardView *)numericKeyboardView DidSelectArrowButton:(UIButton *)arrowButton];
                return;
            case NumericKeyboardViewRightArrow:
                currentTextField = nextTextFieldSelection;
                [self numericKeyboardView:(VS_NumericKeyboardView *)numericKeyboardView DidSelectArrowButton:(UIButton *)arrowButton];
                return;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: are you changing the tag after each call to `numerKeyboardView:DidSelectArrowButton:`?

Comment: Yes, in my logic to change text fields, the left or right text field tag is set depending on how the user is navigating

Comment: You are talking about the nextTextFieldSelection's tag right?

Comment: Yes, when a navigation button is pressed, I find the text field the user chose to navigate to, then set that text field to nextTextFieldSelection with the line `nextTextFieldSelection = (UITextField *)[[_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:destinationIndexPath] viewWithTag:newTag];`.  So all properties, including tags, are set.

Comment: I was hoping you didn't and thats why the infinite loop. :) Anyway did you try putting breakpoints and see which condition is being satisfied for the infinite loop to happen?

Comment: Yes, the condition is that userIneractionEnabled = No to any textfield  outside the visible cells.  This code works if I'm navigating any cells visible.  But once I reach the edges of the table and scrolling must occur, userInteractionEnabled is always set to No

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25302/discussion-between-rakesh-and-jmd)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cellForRowAtIndexPath returns nil for not visible cells. Thats probably why you are getting into that infinite loop.

See: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW16

Comment: boom, this is exactly it.  I suppose I should scroll my view first, THEN check for enabled.

Comment: If I were you I would add all my textfields in an Array. Then you can retrive them even if they are not visible.

Comment: This was my original plan from the get go, but with table cells being re-usable, everything gets completely out of order once the user starts scrolling